# Echo'ing the variable muliple times while reading the variable values from a file

Tags: shell-script, echo, read

I am trying to write a bash script which would read values from a file and echo out the values. But for what ever reason it is not working correctly.
My first file is having the below values

```
Alts Risk UI,6C7D672E-929C-46CD-91C0-28ECB9C94D80,hec_json,app_altrisk_ui
app_compliance,B5F88C9B-8C17-411C-91FE-7166E023168C,_json,app_compliance
app_hsc_ui,1AF6F0EC-6E8D-4BEE-8EDE-4DCDE71F0074,hec_json,app_hsc_ui
app_legal,4FE57959-B948-4BD9-B750-F5E7E84539D8,_json,app_legal
```

and i am trying to write a script like this so that it echo's the values correctly.

```
while IFS="," read name token sourcetype index; do
echo ./acs hec-token create --name $name --default-index $index --default-source-type $sourcetype --default-host sh-i-08d9fbd7e31581bd5.mydomain.com --allowed-indexes $index --use-ack=false --disabled=false --token $token
done < hec.csv
```

iam not sure what exactly is happening but the output is showing something else. I think its because i am referring to $index twice in echo. How do i create a script which shows the output that i need.

The output that i expect is

```
./acs hec-token create --name Alts Risk UI --default-index $index --default-source-type hec_json --default-host sh-i-08d9fbd7e31581bd5.mydomain.com --allowed-indexes app_altrisk_ui --use-ack=false --disabled=false --token 6C7D672E-929C-46CD-91C0-28ECB9C94D80
```

but the output that i am getting is

```
--use-ack=false --disabled=false --token 6C7D672E-929C-46CD-91C0-28ECB9C94D80.com --allowed-indexes app_altrisk_ui
     --use-ack=false --disabled=false --token B5F88C9B-8C17-411C-91FE-7166E023168Cm --allowed-indexes app_compliance
     --use-ack=false --disabled=false --token 1AF6F0EC-6E8D-4BEE-8EDE-4DCDE71F0074.com --allowed-indexes app_hsc_ui
```

Comment: Is the input file a DOS text file? If it is, I would expect that outputting the trailing carriage-return character at the end of `$index` would move the cursor to the first position of the line.  If this is consistent with what you see, convert the input text file from a DOS text file to a Unix text file.

Comment: Please show us what is actually happening. "Something else" isn't very helpful.

Comment: actually @Kusalananda is right. It was the file's fault. the file was an export i created from excel to csv. i just recreated the file as csv and it got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

the file that was having the variables were in a csv format that i exported from an excel. I recreated the variable file using a normal text file and the issue went away.